# Polology of Feynman amplitudes, Section 10.2, Weinberg

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, s-matrix-theory

In Weinberg's QFT Volume 1 section 10.2, we basically find that we have a pole when we have an intermediate particle state; the momentum of the intermediate state is on-shell. I am having trouble understanding this intuitively. Does this mean that one of the internal lines is an on-shell detectable particle now? Aren't internal lines always "virtual", off-shell particles?

Answer (score 2):

In that section, it is when the particular combination of external momenta $q=q_1+q_2+\cdots+q_r=-q_{r+1}-\cdots-q_n$ goes "on-shell", which in this case means $q^2\to -m^2$ for some physical mass in the spectrum of the theory. This combination of external momenta $q$ can be loosely thought of as the momentum of the exchanged internal particle of mass $m$ via momentum conservation. But since these are external momenta, they are definite values (they are not integrated over) that you can toggle at will to find possible poles.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I understand that it is when a subset of the momenta from external legs go on-shell. But the intermediate state (internal line) now is "on-shell". So can we have "on-shell" internal lines? Please let me know if I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: $q$ is what goes on shell, which is built from external momenta. One finds that near this "on shell" point $q^2=-m^2$ the amplitude looks as if there is an internal line that goes like $1/(q^2+m^2-i\epsilon)$ which is not integrated over. This is not to be confused with an actual internal line that comes from a perturbative Feynman diagram expansion. This section of Weinberg deals with the exact amplitude, which he shows has interesting properties near poles.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I understand that we are trying to understand the pole structure non-perturbatively; I think what I am getting confused over is that, as you say, it appears as if an internal line that goes like $\frac{1}{q^2 +m^2 -i\epsilon}$ or goes "on-shell". I also see that this is not an internal line that comes from perturbative expansion, it's from the exact amplitude. Would this mean that in a scattering process an "on-shell" particle can be an intermediate state overall (Figure 10.2 refers it as an elementary particle)? I think there's just some insight I am missing.

Comment: I understand this well if $r = 1$, which means one of the external lines goes on-shell, i.e. one of the incoming particle now is a single-particle state in the theory. We use this to derive LSZ formula in section 10.3. By analogy, does this mean that now $A_1^\dagger....A_r^\dagger \psi_0$ can kind of create a single particle from these external lines? Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

It is [the four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) that carries the meaning of "off shell" , by the invariant mass, if its length is  different than the particle named.

The [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) uses quantum field theory in four dimensions, with the four vectors of Lorentz special relativity. Thus in the SM mass is not a conserved quantity. What is defined is the invariant mass, the length of the four vector , which is invariant under Lorentz transformations.

[Virtual particles](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) in the SM carry the quantum numbers of their name and their propagator has the named particle mass, but are off shell because their mass varies  in the calculation of crossections and decays of the particular interaction calculated, described by the Feynman diagrams.